# Intuition behind uniform ellipticity.

Tags: real-analysis

We say that $A(x)=(a_{ij}(x))_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ a $n\times n$ matrix is uniformly elliptic if there is $\theta >0$ s.t. for all $\xi\in\mathbb R^n$ and all $x\in \Omega $, $$\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j\geq \theta |\xi|^2.$$

Can someone explain where exactly this very weird condition comes from ? I'm not sure to really understand what it means.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as a matrix representing a positive semidefinite bilinear form (scalar product if it is symmetric). If you compute what it means to have $\langle \xi, \xi \rangle \geq 0$ you obtain that formula. The term $\theta$ on the right hand side can be put as (at least with symmetric matrices) the smallest eigenvalue. Such matrices (or operators, in general) are very important in the calculus of variations, for instance, and that hypothesis is essential. See the well known Brezis book “Functional Analysis” for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might come from PDEs, where an elliptic PDE arises from an elliptic operator, e.g. [generalizing the Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator).

Example: Your A(x) could arise from discretizing the Laplacian, operating on u, and in order for $-A < 0 $, being an elliptic PDE, you would need your A to be positive definite, being a matrix.

EDIT: It is "Uniform", since we have $\theta$ independent of $x$, and bounding it away from zero, hence strictly positive.

Comment: The "uniform" part corresponds to the fact that $\theta$ on the right side must be independent of $x$.  If you only had $\sum a_{ij}(x) \xi_i \xi_j \ge \theta(x) |\xi|^2$ for some function $\theta : \Omega \to (0,\infty)$, then the matrix would still be strictly positive for each $x$.  It would be elliptic but not necessarily *uniformly* elliptic, unless $\theta$ was bounded away from 0.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfectly sense.